# How to pass config file to Puma & Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, rack, puma

I have a Sinatra app that's deployed to Heroku.

I want to configure Puma via a `puma.rb` config file to have multiple workers, but both examples from the readme only show how to pass a 'server name' to the `Procfile`, but it doesn't show how to pass a config:

**Method 1**

```
bundle exec ruby app.rb -s puma
```

**Method 2**

```
require 'sinatra'
configure { set :server, :puma }
```

There's all the methods listed here which all suffer the same problem: https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/13#issuecomment-7391148

---

I have my configuration here in `puma.rb`:

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['THREAD_COUNT'] || 5)

threads threads_count, threads_count
```

Here's my `config.ru` if that helps:

```
require './app'
run Sinatra::Application
```

I actually tried doing this instead in `Procfile`:

```
bundle exec puma -c puma.rb
```

Which works perfect locally but then dies in production, but no logs are generated so I have no idea what's wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem as such (the problem was I was missing the rest of the code in `puma.rb` config)

**Procfile**

```
web: bundle exec puma -C puma.rb
```

**puma.rb**

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['THREAD_COUNT'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'
```

**config.ru**

```
require './app'
run Sinatra::Application
```

Answer (score 1):

try upcase `C` and not `c`

```
bundle exec puma -C puma.rb
```

https://github.com/puma/puma#clustered-mode

Comment: I get 'application error' when I do that but it doesnt print out to production log whats wrong